# Changing Worksheet Data in Embedded Excel Worksheet in MS Word FROM ACCESS

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, ms-word

Ok, so I was able to successfully change an embedded Excel worksheet with VBA in a MS Word Document... FROM the code attached to that document.

Now I'm trying to change that same embedded excel worksheet in the MS Word document from MS Access.  I'm successfully connecting to the document and have been able to change other items; like the picture of an Image Content Control, the text of a field in the Header, etc.

I'm using the same code as I did from the actual document.  Here's how I did it from within Word (which worked fine):

```
Dim oleObj as OLEFormat

Set oleObj = Me.Shapes("tblEBACostHistory").OLEFormat
oleObj.Activate
oleObj.Object.Sheets(1).Range("A3") = "test"
SendKeys "{ESC}"
Set oleObj = nothing
```

Here's my code from within Access:

```
Dim oleObj as OLEFormat

Set oleObj = wdDoc.Shapes("tblEBACostHistory").OLEFormat
```

This last line is what fails and gives me a "Type Mismatch" error.  The 'wdDoc' is good because I've been able to make other changes to the document.

Thoughts?

Comment: what if you change `Dim oleObj as Variant`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I answered my own question.  The "Type Mismatch" error was screaming at me that it was some sort of reference library issue.  I had included the Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library, so I couldn't figure out why it was failing.  Then it came to me:

So I changed:

```
Dim oleObj as OLEFormat
```

to:

```
Dim oleObj as Word.OLEFormat
```

And it worked!